# How to control an object that's been created during my app's background activity in flutter/dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, notifications, background

I've been making this flutter app where it plays an alarm while receiving a notification.  When my app is in the foreground, I am able to play or stop the alarm. When it is in the background, once the alarm starts playing after receiving a notification, I am unable to stop it. (It seems like a different instance is being created while in the background. But unfortunately, the FlutterRingtonePlayer.playAlarm() does not return any references to control it.)  Is there any better/alternative way of making this work?

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter_ringtone_player/flutter_ringtone_player.dart';

Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Handling a background message");
  FlutterRingtonePlayer.playAlarm();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('class');
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    }
       @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => FlutterRingtonePlayer.playAlarm(),
                  child: Text('Play Alarm')),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => FlutterRingtonePlayer.stop(),
                  child: Text('Stop Alarm')),
            ])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by using Android Alarm Manager https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager and running both the Play and Stop methods in the background whether the app is in foreground or background.

Instead of FlutterRingtonePlayer.PlayAlarm() and FlutterRingtonePlayer.Stop(), use AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(Duration.zero, 0, _playAlarm); and
AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(Duration.zero, 0, _stopAlarm);

```
{//to play or pause the alarm
onPress()=>AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(Duration.zero, 0, _playAlarm);
onPress()=>AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(Duration.zero, 0, _stopAlarm);
}
// top level functions
void _playAlarm() {
  FlutterRingtonePlayer.playAlarm(volume: 1, looping: true, asAlarm: true);
}
void _stopAlarm() {
  FlutterRingtonePlayer.stop();
}
```